# PHP file to recive data from iOS code isnt working

Tags: php, ios, sql, insert

I am having problems getting my post from my iOS app. I think it is the PHP file. I know it is connecting to the database ok, but it is not inserting the values into the SQL database.

Here is my PHP file in full:

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'username';
$dbpass = 'password';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';


$name =$_GET["name"];
$message = $_GET["message"];

mysqli_query INSERT INTO "test" ("", "name", "message",)
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());


mysql_close();

?>
```

My iOS app is fine, as I am aware and sending the info out fine. But this is the first time i have used PHP.

I'm showing an error on line

```
       mysqli_query INSERT INTO "test" ("", "name", "message",)
```

but not sure, how to solve.

My IOS Code IS as Follows

```
-(void) postMessage: (NSString*) message withName: (NSString *) name{

if (name != nil && message != nil){

    NSMutableString *postString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:kPostURL];

    [postString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"?%@=%@", kName, name]];
    [postString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"&%@=%@", kMessage, message]];
    [postString appendString:[postString    stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL  URLWithString:postString]];


    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    postConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];


}


}


-(IBAction)post:(id)sender{

[self postMessage:messageText.text withName:nameText.text];
[messageText resignFirstResponder];
messageText.text = nil;

nameText.text = nil;



}
```

new php code

```
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';

$name =$_GET["name"];
$message = $_GET["message"];

mysql_query("INSERT INTO test ('', $name, $message)") or die(mysql_error()); 


mysql_close();

?>
```

---

extra info

---

the app is just a view controller with 
a TextField , TextView, and a button as in the .h file

```
#define kPostURL @"http://www.dmk-media.com/taxi/tuttest.php"
#define kName @"name"
#define kMessage @"message"




@interface DMKFirstViewController : UIViewController{


IBOutlet UITextField *nameText;
IBOutlet UITextView  *messageText;
NSURLConnection *postConnection;


}

-(IBAction)post:(id)sender;
```

and then to post the message

```
-(void) postMessage: (NSString*) message withName: (NSString *) name{

if (name != nil && message != nil){

    NSMutableString *postString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:kPostURL];

    [postString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"?%@=%@", kName, name]];
    [postString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"&%@=%@", kMessage, message]];
    [postString appendString:[postString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL  URLWithString:postString]];


    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    postConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];


}


}
```

and then the button action

```
-(IBAction)post:(id)sender{

[self postMessage:messageText.text withName:nameText.text];
[messageText resignFirstResponder];
messageText.text = nil;

nameText.text = nil;



}
```

thats all the is in the code its just a basic app to try and test posting to my sql server

Comment: First: you are mixing mysql and mysqli. Second: does your iOS app call a GET or POST request?

Comment: post check my edit i have put in the ios code

Comment: So you do get data from iOS app but can't store it to database? Leonardo's answer should help. The problem is you are mixing [mysql](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) and [mysqli](http://www.php.net/mysqli): this are two different APIs

Comment: i have changed that area but still not posting results

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove:

```
$name =$_GET["name"];
$message = $_GET["message"];

...

mysqli_query INSERT INTO "test" ("", "name", "message",)
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

It should be:

```
$name = $_POST["name"];
$message = $_POST["message"];
mysql_select_db('DATABASE_NAME', $conn) or die(mysql_error());

...

mysql_query("INSERT INTO test(name, mesage) VALUES ('$name', '$message');", $conn) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: @MikeAsp check my updated answer, I changed this line: `mysql_query("INSERT INTO test ('', $name, $message)", $conn) or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: that got rid of the errors. but im still getting no data going in to the SQL database. the iphone seems to be posting ok but the data is getting lost somewhere

Comment: use a **DBMS** like MySQL Workbench or phpMyAdmin and execute this query: `SHOW COLUMNS FROM test` and post that response in your question. What I want to see is the _data types_ and _keys_ of your columns

Comment: @MikeAsp see my updated answer: I changed this line: `mysql_query("INSERT INTO test(name, mesage) VALUES ($name, $message)", $conn) or die(mysql_error()); `. This should definitely work...

Comment: nope nothing http://www.dmk-media.com/taxi/tuttest.php See Error when you go to the url

Comment: @MikeAsp see my updated answer, I added this line after the `$message` variable declaration: `mysql_select_db('test', $conn);`

Comment: @MikeAsp what is your database name?

Comment: @MikeAsp I updated my answer, in the line: `mysql_select_db('DATABASE_NAME', $conn);` you should write the database name instead of the table name..

Comment: yes that connected but its saying theres an error in the line mysql_query("INSERT INTO test(name, mesage) VALUES ($name, $message)", $conn) or die(mysql_error()); go to http://www.dmk-media.com/taxi/tuttest.php to see error

Comment: @MikeAsp I updated the last line of my answer..it should work!

Comment: SOLVED IT thanks to your help ...... mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (name,message) VALUES ('$name','$message');", 
$conn) or die(mysql_error());

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void) postMessage: (NSString*) message withName: (NSString *) name{

    if (name != nil && message != nil){
        NSMutableString *postString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:kPostURL];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:postString]];
        NSString *param = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@&%@=%@",kName, name, kMessage, message];
        request.HTTPBody = [param dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
        postConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    }
}
```

Comment: you should add a quick description of what was changed and what your doing for more clarity

Comment: added extra details at the bottom of my post